# getimagesize with Laravel 4 Blade template

Tags: php, laravel

How can I use getimagesize using Laravel 4's blade template?

I have the following foreach loop:

```
@foreach($category as $inventory)
   {{ HTML::image('small/' . $inventory->image . '', '' . $inventory->name . '', array('class' => 'scale-with-grid', 'height' => '280', 'width' => 'auto')); }}

@endforeach
```

I want the `getimagesize` function to display the height and width for that specific image in the `height` and `width` image attributes. Every time I attempted to do it myself but could not get it working correctly.

**EDIT**

This is what I have tried so far. I think my biggest problem is I am not sure how to access the small folder inside my public directory. I tried using public_path but it's returning a array to string conversion error. However, it seems like when I dump public_path it shows the correct path.

```
{{ $image = getimagesize(public_path('small/' . $inventory->image . '')) }}

{{ var_dump($image); die; }}
```

I am using wamp and when I dump public_path this is the first source I get.

```
string 'C:\wamp\www\product\public/small/image.jpg' (length=71)
```

I am not sure if that's the issue. When I copy and paste that into my browser it will load the image with no problem

Comment: how about you get the info you need inside a controller?

Comment: I agree with @sikhlana. There's no reason not to do this in the controller and pass the information as part of an array to the blade template.

Comment: Not sure how to pass this through the controller when I use the foreach loop in the blade template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("Full path of the image");
```

Now you can use $width and $height.

Comment: I think that would work. But I am getting a array to string conversion error. Not sure why that's happening.

Comment: The issue was {{ }} is similar to <?php echo ?>, but the getimagesize was returning an array of size 7. I hope you understand what the issue was :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by not using blade brackets and inserting

```
   <?php list($width, $height) = getimagesize(asset('small/' . $inventory->image . ''));  ?>

   {{ HTML::image('small/' . $inventory->image . '', '' . $inventory->name . '', array('class' => 'scale-with-grid', 'height' => 280, 'width' => $width)); }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest against writing such a code in controller. If you need to repeat this somewhere else (which is the case most of the time) then writing it in controller is a bad idea. Keep you controllers simple. I would probably solve this in my repository or something like that... but if its small project that i suggest defining HTML::macro

```
HTML::macro('imageWithSize', function($url, $alt = null, $attributes = array(), $secure = null)
{
    // original - HTMl::image($url, $alt = null, $attributes = array(), $secure = null);

    // get image path  - change this to whatever suits you
    $image_path = public_path($url);

    // get image size 
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_path);
    // add those to attributes array
    $attributes['width'] = $width;
    $attributes['height'] = $height;

    return HTML::image($url, $alt, $attributes, $secure );
});
```

You can see the original implementatio of HTML::image [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Html/HtmlBuilder.php#L109)